# Foreach looping trouble and output

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

First off, I am really not that experienced with PHP, and the best practises to use, so please, be nice ;)

Anyway, I am struggling with a google analytics output to a java table, where my foreach to display pagehits and pageviews, does not listen to me at all :/

Just to clearify, There is nothing wrong with the array, when foreaching values in a regular table, they are correct. I am quite sure there is something with my foreach and perhaps some counting of loops or ?? have no idea?

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ga:date=20110930&start-date=2011-09-30&end-date=2011-10-15 [updated] => 2011-10-14T17:00:00.001-07:00 [title] => ga:date=20110930 [dimensions] => Array ( [name] => date [value] => 20110930 ) [metrics] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [confidenceInterval] => 0.0 [name] => newVisits [type] => integer [value] => 4 ) 

[1] => Array ( [id] => http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?date=20111001&start-date=2011-09-30&end-date=2011-10-15 [updated] => 2011-10-14T17:00:00.001-07:00 [title] => ga:date=20111001 [dimensions] => Array ( [name] => date [value] => 20111001 ) [metrics] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [confidenceInterval] => 0.0 [name] => newVisits [type] => integer [value] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [confidenceInterval] => 0.0 [name] => uniquePageviews [type] => integer [value] => 54 ) ) )

and so on.
```

And now my foreaching:
Note: metricsarray => (uniquePageviews + NewVisits), just for the titles

```
<?php if (!empty($metricsArray)): ?>
           <?php foreach ($metricsArray as $m): ?>

            <tr>
            <th><?php echo $m ?></th> <!-- To display UniqueHits and Pageviews titles-->

                <?php 
                foreach ($account['Account']['dataPoints'] as $data): ?>

                    <?php if (!empty($data['metrics'])): ?>

                    <?php foreach ($data['metrics'] as $key => $val): ?>

                    <?php if (is_numeric($key)): ?>

                    <td><?php echo $val['value'] ?></td>

                    <?php elseif ($key == 'value'): ?>

                    <td><?php echo $val ?></td>

                    <?php endif ?>

                    <?php endforeach ?>

                    <?php endif ?>

                 <?php endforeach ?>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
       <?php endif ?>
```

My problem is that this output like this:

```
<tr>
<th>NewVisits</th>
<td>1</td>  <!-- Unique visit
<td>7</td>  <!-- PageViews
<td>2</td>  <!-- Uniwue hit
<td>7</td>  <!-- PageViews
+++++
</tr>

<tr>
<th>NUniquePageviews</th>
<td>1</td>  <!-- Unique visit
<td>7</td>  <!-- PageViews
<td>2</td>  <!-- Uniwue hit
<td>7</td>  <!-- PageViews
+++++
</tr>
```

My problem here, is that it display the exact same in both TR, with the exception of the TH title text. 
It should display Unique vistis only in TR 1, and Pageviews in TR2.

Thanks for any input on this..

Kind Regards!
-Tom

Answer (score 0):

Whatever variable `$account` is, it's looping through the same array every iteration of `$metricsArray as $m`.

Comment: Yes I know,, but I am not sure how to get it to not loop that way. And only output the Unique hits values on first loop, and pageviews on second loop.

Comment: Preferably, you should have all info in `$metricsArray` and just iterate through it. The way it is now, you have just titles in `$metricsArray` and somewhere before (in code not shown) you set `$account`, which is array with only one item.

Comment: I know I should have all in metricsarray, but you are wrong about the $account array. It contains 15 google analytics items (1 for each day = 15 days). I am not sure how to get the values to the metricsarray, but I will look into it. If any other suggestion on how to count or whatnot, the loop values, to display them correct from the $account array??

Comment: oh, sorry, I meant there's just one item in `$account['Account']['dataPoints']`.